# react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, redux

I want to add live chat function like another screen in my app. And when I creaetd this screen and open the browser and click on Support button , where is live chat screen , in the console write :

```
ERROR
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
    at useReduxContext (http://localhost:3000/main.50916dccf941eef38050.hot-update.js:55675:13)
    at useSelector (http://localhost:3000/main.50916dccf941eef38050.hot-update.js:55764:9)
    at SupportScreen (http://localhost:3000/main.50916dccf941eef38050.hot-update.js:5426:78)
    at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:76901:22)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:80187:17)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81483:20)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66493:18)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66537:20)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:66594:35)
    at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:86468:11)
```

In index.js , i added StoreProvider , but it doesn't work. Please, can you help me ?
I add my code about live chat screen (SupportScreen.js) and index.js.

**SupportScreen.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import MessageBox from '../components/MessageBox';

let allUsers = [];
let allMessages = [];
let allSelectedUser = {};
const ENDPOINT = 
    window.location.host.indexOf('localhost') >= 0
    ? 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
    : window.location.host;

export default function SupportScreen() {
    const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState({});
    const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
    const uiMessagesRef = useRef(null);
    const [messageBody, setMessageBody] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const userSignin = useSelector((state)=> state.userSignin);
    const {userInfo} = userSignin;

    useEffect(()=> {
        if(uiMessagesRef.current){
            uiMessagesRef.current.scrollBy({
                top: uiMessagesRef.current.clientHeight,
                left: 0,
                behavior: 'smooth',
            });

            if(!socket){
                const sk = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
                setSocket(sk);
                sk.emit('onLogin', {
                    _id: userInfo._id,
                    name: userInfo.name,
                    isAdmin: userInfo.isAdmin
                });
                sk.on('message', (data)=> {
                    if(allSelectedUser._id === data._id){
                        allMessages = [...allMessages, data];
                    }else{
                        const existUser = allUsers.find((user)=> user._id === data._id);
                        if(existUser){
                            allUsers=allUsers.map((user)=>
                            user._id === existUser._id ? {...user, unread: true} : user
                            );
                            setUsers(allUsers);
                        }
                    }
                
                setMessages(allMessages);
            });
    
            sk.on('updateUser', (updatedUser)=> {
                const existUser = allUsers.find((user)=> user._id === updatedUser._id);
                if(existUser) {
                    allUsers= allUsers.map((user)=>
                    user._id === existUser._id ? updatedUser : user
                    );
                    setUsers(allUsers);
                }else{
                    allUsers = [...allUsers, updatedUser];
                    setUsers(allUsers);
                }
            });
    
            sk.on('listUsers', (updatedUsers)=> {
                allUsers = updatedUsers;
                setUsers(allUsers);
            });
    
            sk.on('selectUser', (user)=> {
                allMessages = user.messages;
                setMessages(allMessages);
            });
            }

           

    }
    }, [messages, socket, users, userInfo._id, userInfo.isAdmin, userInfo.name]);

    const selectUser = (user)=>{
        allSelectedUser=user;
        setSelectedUser(allSelectedUser);
        const existUser = allUsers.find((x)=> x._id === user._id);
        if(existUser){
            allUsers = allUsers.map((x)=>
            x._id === existUser._id ? {...x, unread: false}: x
            );
            setUsers(allUsers);
        }
        socket.emit('onUserSelected', user);
    };

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!messageBody.trim()){
            alert('Error. Please type message.');
        }else {
            allMessages = [
                ...allMessages,
                {body: messageBody, name: userInfo.name}
            ];
            setMessages(allMessages);
            setMessageBody('');
            setTimeout(()=> {
                socket.emit('onMessage', {
                    body: messageBody,
                    name: userInfo.name,
                    isAdmin: userInfo.isAdmin,
                    _id: selectedUser._id
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

  return (
    <div className='row top full-container'>
        <div className='col-1 support-users'>
            {users.filter((x)=> x._id !== userInfo._id).length === 0 && (
                <MessageBox>No Online User Found</MessageBox>
            )}
            <ul>
                {users.filter((x)=> x._id !== userInfo._id)
                .map((user)=>(
                    <li key={user._id} className={user._id === selectedUser._id ? ' selected' : ' ' } >
                        <button className='block' type="block" onClick={()=> selectUser(user)}>
                            {user.name}
                        </button>
                        <span className={user.unread ? 'unread' : user.online ? 'online' : 'offline'
                         }
                        />
                       
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div className='col-3 support-messages'>
            {!selectedUser._id ? (
                <MessageBox>Select a user to start chat</MessageBox>
               ): (
                <div>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <strong>Chat with {selectedUser.name} </strong>
                    </div>
                    <ul ref={uiMessagesRef}>
                        {messages.length === 0 && <li>No message.</li>}
                        {messages.map((msg, index)=> (
                            <li key={index}>
                                <strong>{`${msg.name}: `}</strong> {msg.body}
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={submitHandler} className='row'>
                            <input
                             value={messageBody}
                             onChange={(e)=>setMessageBody(e.target.value)}
                             type="text"
                             placeholder="type message"
                            />
                            <button type="submit">Sent</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {HelmetProvider} from 'react-helmet-async';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { StoreProvider } from './Store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StoreProvider>
      <HelmetProvider>
        <App />
      </HelmetProvider>
    </StoreProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {ToastContainer} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen";
import CarScreen from './screens/CarScreen';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import {LinkContainer} from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import SigninScreen from './screens/SigninScreen';
import { Store } from './Store';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import PersonalDataScreen from './screens/PersonalDataScreen';
import SignupScreen from './screens/SignupScreen.';
import PaymentMethodScreen from './screens/PaymentMethodScreen';
import PlaceOrderScreen from './screens/PlaceOrderScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './screens/ProfileScreen';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import DashboardScreen from './screens/DashboardScreen';
import AdminRoute from './components/AdminRoute';
import CarListScreen from './screens/CarListScreen';
import CarEditScreen from './screens/CarEditScreen';
import UserListScreen from './screens/UserListScreen';
import UserEditScreen from './screens/UserEditScreen';
import SearchBox from './components/SearchBox';
import CartScreen from './screens/CartScreen';
import Badge from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Badge';
import SupportScreen from './screens/SupportScreen';





function App() {
  const {state, dispatch: ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store)
  const {cart, userInfo} = state;

  const signoutHandler = () =>{
    ctxDispatch({type: 'USER_SIGNOUT'});
    localStorage.removeItem('userInfo');
    localStorage.removeItem('personalData');
    localStorage.removeItem('paymentMethod');
    window.location.href= '/signin';
  };


  return (
    
    <BrowserRouter>
        
          <ToastContainer position="botton-center" limit={1} />
          <header>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
              <Container>
               
                <LinkContainer to="/">
                  <Navbar.Brand>carRental</Navbar.Brand>
                </LinkContainer>
                <SearchBox />
                <Nav className='me-auto'>
                    <Link to="/cart" className='nav-link'>
                      Reservations
                      {cart.cartItems.length > 0 && (
                        <Badge pill bg="danger">
                          {cart.cartItems.length}
                          
                        </Badge>
                      )}
                      </Link>
                </Nav>
                <Nav className="me-auto">
                  {userInfo ? (
                    <NavDropdown title={userInfo.name} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                      <LinkContainer to="/profile">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>User Profile</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/orderhistory">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Order History</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <NavDropdown.Divider />
                      <Link className='dropdown-item' to="#signout" onClick={signoutHandler}>Sign out</Link>

                    </NavDropdown>
                  ):(
                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/signin">
                    Sign In
                    </Link>
                  )}

                  {userInfo && userInfo.isAdmin && (
                    <NavDropdown title="Admin" id="admin-nav-dropdown">
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/dashboard">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Dashboard</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/cars">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Cars</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/order">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Orders</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/users">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Users</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                      <LinkContainer to="/admin/support">
                        <NavDropdown.Item>Support</NavDropdown.Item>
                      </LinkContainer>
                    </NavDropdown>
                  )}
                </Nav>
              </Container>
            </Navbar>
          </header>
          <main>
            <Container className='mt-3'>
              <Routes>
                <Route path="/car/:model" element={<CarScreen />} />
                <Route path="/signin" element={<SigninScreen />} />
                <Route path="/signup" element={<SignupScreen />} />
                <Route path="/profile" element={
                <ProtectedRoute>
                  <ProfileScreen />
                </ProtectedRoute>} />
                <Route path="/personalData" element={<PersonalDataScreen />} />
                <Route path="/payment" element={<PaymentMethodScreen />} />
                {/* Admin routes */}
                <Route path="/admin/dashboard" 
                element={<AdminRoute><DashboardScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                 <Route path="/admin/support" 
                element={<AdminRoute><SupportScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                  <Route path="/admin/cars" 
                element={<AdminRoute><CarListScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                <Route path="/admin/car/:id" 
                element={<AdminRoute><CarEditScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 

                <Route path="/admin/user/:id" 
                element={<AdminRoute><UserEditScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                 <Route path="/admin/users" 
                element={<AdminRoute><UserListScreen /></AdminRoute>}></Route> 
                <Route path="/placeorder" element={<PlaceOrderScreen />} />
                <Route path="/cart" element={<CartScreen />} />
                <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
              </Routes>   
            </Container>        
          </main>
          <footer>
            <div className="text-center">All rights reserved</div>
          </footer>
       
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Store.js**

```
import {createContext, useReducer} from 'react';

export const Store = createContext();

const initialState = {
    userInfo: localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
    : null,

    cart: {
        cartItems: localStorage.getItem('cartItems')
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems'))
        : [],
        personalData: localStorage.getItem('personalData')
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('personalData'))
        : {},
        paymentMethod: localStorage.getItem('paymentMethod')
        ? localStorage.getItem('paymentMethod')
        : '',
    }
};

function reducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CART_ADD_ITEM':
            //add to cart
            const newItem = action.payload;
            const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find(
                (item)=> item._id === newItem._id
            );
            const cartItems = existItem 
            ? state.cart.cartItems.map((item)=>
                item._id === existItem._id ? newItem : item
            )
            : [...state.cart.cartItems, newItem];
            localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            return {...state, cart: {...state.cart, cartItems}};

        case 'CART_REMOVE_ITEM': {
            const cartItems = state.cart.cartItems.filter(
                (item) => item._id !== action.payload._id
            );
            localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            return {...state, cart: {...state.cart, cartItems}};
        }

        case 'USER_SIGNIN':
            return {...state, userInfo:action.payload};
        case "USER_SIGNOUT":
            return {
                ...state,
                userInfo:null,
                cart: {
                    cartItems: [],
                    personalData: {},
                    paymentMethod: '',
                },
            };
        case 'SAVE_PERSONAL_DATA':
            return{
                ...state,
                cart: {
                    ...state.cart,
                    personalData: action.payload,
                },
            };
        case 'SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD':
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: {...state.cart, paymentMethod: action.payload},
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export function StoreProvider(props) {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    const value = {state, dispatch};
    return <Store.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</Store.Provider>
}
```

Comment: Show the code of the `StoreProvider` component

Comment: I added code of Store.js .